# How to filter the data with ranges of number?

Tags: r, dataframe

My `dput` for the data:

> structure(list(ID = c(8934L, 8934L, 8934L, 8934L, 8934L, 8934L),
> index.date = c("2004-07-15", "2004-07-15", "2004-07-15", "2004-07-15",
> "2004-07-15", "2004-07-15"), medication.or.not = c(0L, 0L, 0L,  0L,
> 0L, 0L), Reference.date = c("1998-03-14", "1998-03-03",  "1998-03-14",
> "1998-02-06", "2004-07-20", "2004-07-20"), DX.Code.ICD9 = c("416.9",
> "276.2", "137.0", "519.8", "295.40", "137.0"), row.names = c(NA,  6L),
> class = "data.frame")

I checked the data with sapply and the code is character. How should I transform the whole column to numeric when there is a string in the code, e.g. E87, V70.5

Here is an example of my data:

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 295 |
| 2 | 295.15 |
| 3 | 297 |
| 4 | 298.92 |
| 5 | 398 |
| 6 | 515 |
| 7 | E87 |

I want to select the row that the code with 295-295.99 and 297-298.99 only.
So I try to use filter, which is:

`dataframe <- data.list %>% filter(Code %in% (295:295.9 & 297:298.9))`

However, it doesn't work at all. How can I select the role I want by filtering it?

Comment: `data.list %>% filter(Code %>% between(295,295.9) | Code %>% between(297,298.9))`

Comment: I have tried the code and it said "Warning messages:
1: In between(., 295, 295.99) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In between(., 297, 298.99) : NAs introduced by coercion"

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can share an example of your data in the form of code, for instance by running `dput(head(data.list))` and including the output in your question. Your error makes me wonder if your Code data is character or factor, which is not the same as the numbers in that range.

Comment: structure(list(ID = c(8934L, 8934L, 8934L, 8934L, 8934L, 8934L
), index.date = c("2004-07-15", "2004-07-15", "2004-07-15", "2004-07-15", 
"2004-07-15", "2004-07-15"), medication.or.not = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), DX.date = c("1998-03-14", "1998-03-03", 
"1998-03-14", "1998-02-06", "2004-07-20", "2004-07-20"), Code = c("416.9", 
"276.2", "137.0", "519.8", "295.40", "137.0"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame") @JonSpring

Comment: Put that in the question.  Also you seem to be adding "."  to @JonSpring 's code.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
df %>% filter(between(Code,  295, 295.99) | between(Code, 297, 298.99)) %>% as.data.frame()
  ID   Code
1  1 295.00
2  2 295.15
3  3 297.00
4  4 298.92
```